# Rails 3 and rspec - select from select list

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, selectlist

I want to select value from select list in **RSpec**. For example i have such data:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="user_teacher_leader_attributes_teacher_id">Teacher names</label>
  <div class="controls">
   <select id="user_teacher_leader_attributes_teacher_id" name="user[teacher_leader_attributes][teacher_id]">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Math teacher</option>
    <option value="2">Physics teacher</option>       
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select option `Physics teacher` via **RSpec**. How can i do that? Also, can i choose something from the list by value (for example, select `Physics teacher` by value "2" which it has)?

Comment: You need `have_selector` matcher

Comment: @Mik_Die Why should i use matcher to select option? Are you sure?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found solution. You should use **select** method:

```
select "Physics teacher", :from => "teacher_leader[teacher_id]"
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with `select` that has an option twice? (e.g. `'United States'` is twice in my country-select to have some "priority countries" for better UX)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Which sucks because I had the same question. How to select by `value` not option `text`?